# HTML Margin/Padding Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've a question about how to change the margins using the predefined classes of Bootstrap 3. What I want to do in my case is to set the bottom margin of a 'div' to 0 (I know perfectly that I can just create an Id or a Class and write a line in the css, but it means not using properly bootstrap).

I read this [documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/)

and as you can read, I must to put "m-b-0" (in my case) that it's equals to write in the css "margin-bottom: 0em;", but it doesn't works. Now, do you know if there is something similar for version 3 of bootstrap (or why doesn't works)?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a version issue.

Use `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css`

This is version 4 where those utilities are valid. 3.5.5 does not support.

Hope this resolves your issue!